# No reimbursement for job interview travel expenses

Tags: germany, workplace

I have [already asked on the workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/151254/no-reimbursement-for-travel-expenses-after-two-months) about how to ask for reimbursement that was agreed on before a job interview. I'm gonna briefly summarize here what has happened so far.
After applying for a job in another German city, the company offered to pay for my travel expenses. I submitted a form that they provided along with the original receipt for my ticket. After a few interviews with the company (both on-site and later online) I decided that I did not want to work for them any longer and therefore withdrew my application via email. They did not reimburse me or reply to an email I sent recently regarding the reimbursement. The email was along the lines of:

> Hey, I haven't heard back from you regarding the reimbursement. Could
>   you give me an update on that matter?

I would like to get reimbursed for my travel expenses (close to 200€). What further steps can I take now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they have allready given you a form to fill that you have sent back with the original receipts, I will assume that the major preconditions have been fulfilled (mainly that they have asked you to come in writing and have **not** exclude reimbursement).

This a case of civil law based on [§670 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2925).

Since they have not fullfilled their obligation, you must send them a reminder (**Mahnung**) in the form of a registered letter, requiring them to do so within a reasonable timeframe (like 10 working days after receipt of the letter).

- look for standard letters on this topic (Mahnungen)

The letter should be descriptive in nature (i.e. a Judge, after reading a copy of the letter, will understand the whole situation).

Nowadays such a letter should be sent through your local Amsgericht, so that they can certify that your copy of the letter was included in the original letter.

If they don't react to this, then you must charge them.

This is a basic description of the needed method.

Look up the details of the process and/or for someone to assist you.

---

> **Section 670**
>   **Reimbursement of expenses**
>
> If the mandatary, for the purpose of performing the mandate, incurs expenses that he may consider to be necessary in the circumstances, then the mandator is obliged to make reimbursement.

---

**Sources**

- [§670 - German Civil Code (BGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2925)
- [Wer trägt die Reisekosten für das Vorstellungsgespräch? - ingenieur.de](https://www.ingenieur.de/karriere/bewerbung/wer-zu-einem-vorstellungsgespraech-eingeladen-wird-sollte-die-fahrtkosten-erstattet-bekommen/)